# Self transfer in Dubai. Do I need a visa?

Tags: transit-visas, dubai, belgian-citizens, azerbaijani-citizens, self-transfer

I am belgien citizen. I m Azerbaijan citizen too..I want to fly to Belgium from Azerbaijan through Dubai but there is a self transfer and I don't have luggage. Do I need Dubai visa ?
For information I want to add that I am leaving Azerbaijan with Azerbaijan passport but from Dubai to Belgium will use Belgium passport.

Anybody knows do I need Dubai visa?

Answer (score 5):

Belgian citizens don't need a visa to enter UAE. What passport you show when leaving Azerbaijan or to your airline doesn't matter to the UAE authorities. You can just show them your Belgian passport. You must then show the same passport when leaving UAE.

Comment: OP should use Belgian passport at check in Azerbaijan but use  Azerbaijan passport at exit control